# WindowsMediaPlayer KeyDown Event in VB6

Tags: vb6

I want to create a virtual piano using VB6.
My program will use the KeyDown event, so I wrote this:

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Sift As Integer)
   If KeyCode = VbKeyQ then
      WindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = App.Path & "\sound_bank\C2.wav"
   End If
End Sub
```

Everything is good, the sound is played when I pressed Q on my keyboard but,
when I hold the Q the sound is stop before its duration length.

Say the duration of C2.wav is 10 second, when I just press and release the Q on keyboard it's played full duration of C2.wav (10s), but when I press and holding the Q on keyboard its just played C2.wav on 4 second. And I saw status of WMP is changed to Connecting... from Playing when I hold the key.

So, how to make it not stop/ cut the duration of C2.wav when I hold the key?

Comment: Thanks, but still not work. I saw status of my WindowsMediaPlayer1 is changed to connecting from playing when I hold the key.

Comment: Of course it does. The event fires several times a second when you hold the key and each time you reset the `URL`. You should either completely rethink your approach and e.g. use a timer and something like `GetAsyncKeyState`, or ignore all `KeyDown` events until a `KeyUp` is registered.

Comment: @GSerg Oke, so how I can make the event is only fire once ? I was learned and tried using `GetAsyncKeyState` but its same, can you give me example code please ?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

You may fire a timer for certain intervals to play C2.wav when KeyDown event fired and stop the timer on KeyUp event.